# BIRT Define JNDI Connection in Eclipse Report Designer

Tags: jndi, birt

I'm trying to design a BIRT report using the report designer plugin in eclipse that will use a JNDI connection. I have found several sources mention that its possible to create a "jndi.properties" file with the datasource properties but nowhere that mentions what properties i should specify, could someone please provide an example JNDI definition?

Comment: following link has solution for your problem , https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/jndi-database-connections/